# How does one get the "modern" style in the ServiceCloud Console

Tags: service-cloud-console, style

We have just enabled the Console in our sandbox and it looks awful - totally retro style with loads of green and "3d" silver tabs - basically a look from 5 years ago instead of the new blue.

[image: fugly]

Why is this and how can we change it to the new style? Something like this baby:

[image: modern]

Answer (score 0):

The service cloud console (what you want) and the console tab (what you're seeing) are two different things. To get access to the service cloud console, you'll need to create a Service Cloud Console enabled app. This is not a big of a deal as it sounds.

- Go to Setup, Create, Apps and click "New". Select "Console" on the first screen to create a Service Cloud Console enabled app.
- Check "Service Cloud User" on your User record.

When you switch into the new app, you should see that layout.

See also: http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/console2_define_app.htm

Comment: Remember the Console (for service or for sales) is a paid add-on so you need licences and your user have the licence assigned to it.